# Hibernate @OneToMany and UNIQUE constraint

Tags: hibernate

I'm using Hibernate to store information about article citations. And I annotated my class in this way in order to express a relationship between two articles.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "CITATIONS")
private Set<Article> citingArticles = new HashSet<Article>();
```

Unfortunately this is translated with a UNIQUE constraint on the citingArticle, which means that I can only have an article to cite a single other article.

Of course this is not what I'd like to have, how can I remove the UNIQUE constraint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a many-to-many relationship, you need to model it with `@ManyToMany`:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY) 
@JoinTable(name = "CITATIONS") 
private Set<Article> citingArticles = new HashSet<Article>();
```

Comment: What? No.... he wants *one* thing to reference *many* other things. In a join table that would be one column for the one thing (whatever class this `Set` of articles is in), and another *non-unique* column for the many things (the `Article`s). He doesn't want a many-to-many, he just wants one-to-many, and that shouldn't yeild a unique constraint on the many column.

Comment: @MattPowell I have a similar problem, one entity to reference many of the second entity, but it still puts a unique constraint, and I'm convinced it is a one-to-many, so what do you think is the solution?

Comment: @Aria Have you managed to find a solution in the time that have passed?

Answer (score -1):

Have you see discussion at https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3410

It seems that the `@OneToMany` is understand differently in hibernate context.

Consider you have an `Article` entity which could have many `Tags`. Also  each `Article` could have many `Comments` too.

You define some thing like this

```
Class Article 

    @OneToMany
    List<Comment>

    @OneToMany
    List<Tag>
```

Looking from `Comments` table perspective. You do not associate one `Comment` to more than one `Article` . Logically it is not correct. So generating the unique constraint seems correct here.

Now Look from `Tags` table perspective. It is correct that one `Tag` could be assigned to many `Articles`. So the unique constraint here generate problem and need to be changed to `@ManyToMany`